# assigning Images through adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am Making one Medical Application

I want to show ListView for Prescription including Medicine Name ,Timing and Image.all values are coming from database except images.

Means if Medicine Type from Database is Tablet than I want to Show ImgA an if Medicine Type if Injection then I want to show ImgB in ListView.

Here is My Activity:

```
public Integer[] Images = {R.drawable.tablet,R.drawable.injection};
public Integer[] ImageId = new Integer[]{} ;
```

this is how i Assigning Images :

```
 Cursor cur = dop.getPrescriptionData();
Integer Length = cur.getCount();
        if(cur!= null && cur.getCount()>0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    ImageId = new Integer[Length];
                    if(MedicineType == 1){ImageId[i] = Images[0];}
                    else if(MedicineType == 0){ImageId[i]= Images[1];
                    //other Parameters
                     i++;
                   }
                while (cur.moveToNext());
               }
           }
        }
```

Passing Values to my Adapter:

```
PrescriptionAdapter pAdapter = new PrescriptionAdapter(PrescriptionActivity.this,ImageId,MedicineName,MedicineType,MedicineTimings,subMedicineTiming);
        lstPrescription.setAdapter(pAdapter);
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class PrescriptionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Context context;
public ArrayList<String>MedicineNames;
public ArrayList<String>MedicineType;
public ArrayList<String>MedicineTimings;
public ArrayList<String>subMedicineTimings;
public Integer[] ImageId = new Integer[]{};

public PrescriptionAdapter(Context context,Integer[] ImageId,ArrayList<String>MedicineNames,ArrayList<String>MedicineType,
                           ArrayList<String>MedicineTimings,ArrayList<String>subMedicineTimings)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.ImageId = ImageId;
    this.MedicineNames = MedicineNames;
    this.MedicineType = MedicineType;
    this.MedicineTimings  = MedicineTimings;
    this.subMedicineTimings = subMedicineTimings;
}
public int getCount(){return MedicineNames.size();}
public Object getItem(int Position){return null;}
public long getItemId(int Position){return 0;}
public class viewHolder{
    TextView tvMedicineName;
    ImageView imgMedicineType;
    TextView tvMedicineTiming;
    TextView tvSubMedicineTiming;
}
@Override
public View getView(int Position,View Child,ViewGroup Parent)
{
    try
    {
        viewHolder vHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflator;

        if(Child == null)
        {
            inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Child = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_prescription_row,Parent,false);
            vHolder = new viewHolder();
            vHolder.tvMedicineName = (TextView)Child.findViewById(R.id.txtMedicineName);
            vHolder.tvMedicineTiming = (TextView)Child.findViewById(R.id.txtMedicineTiming);
            vHolder.tvSubMedicineTiming = (TextView)Child.findViewById(R.id.txtSubMedicineTiming);
            vHolder.imgMedicineType = (ImageView)Child.findViewById(R.id.imgPrescription);
            Child.setTag(vHolder);
        }
        else {vHolder = (viewHolder)Child.getTag();}
        vHolder.tvMedicineName.setText(MedicineNames.get(Position));
        vHolder.tvMedicineTiming.setText(MedicineTimings.get(Position));
        vHolder.tvSubMedicineTiming.setText(subMedicineTimings.get(Position));
        vHolder.imgMedicineType.setImageResource(ImageId[Position]);
        return Child;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

I am getting issue in getView() for setting Image:

Here is my Logcat:

```
05-04 10:58:21.694 15911-15911/com.example.pranita.niramay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1168)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1251)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1160)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1374)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:663)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1374)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:663)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2110)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1147)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove the Image Part from my code,the code is working fine..it gives me issue while setting ImageView.

How to resolve it????

this is my xml file

```
<!--language:xml-->
><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE LinearLayout>
><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rlListPrescriptionRow"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgPrescription"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPrescription"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtMedicineName"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMedicineName"
        android:id="@+id/txtMedicineTiming"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtMedicineName"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtSubMedicineTiming"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMedicineTiming"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtMedicineTiming"
        android:typeface="serif"
 >       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
></RelativeLayout>



></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: duplicate question [`java.lang.NullPointerException`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: try using picaso library

Comment: put 'public Integer[] Images = {R.drawable.tablet,R.drawable.injection};' into onCreate.. may this solve the nullpointwr exception

Comment: Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(image_url)
                .into(holder.image);
it is used like this

Comment: Can you add the code where you are creating the adapter?

Comment: Probably Child.findViewById(R.id.imgPrescription) is returning null

Comment: @prakshi please have look on my answer....i think it solve your problem.........

Comment: shere your  list_prescription_row.xml .

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this issue

what i done is: I took Integer Arraylist for storing my Images

**In my Main Activity**

```
 public int[] Images = {R.drawable.imgA,R.drawable.imgB};
 public ArrayList<Integer>ImageId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 int i = 0;

if(cur.moveToFirst()){
if(MedicineType == 1)
                    {
                        ImageId.add(Images[0]);
                    }
                    else if(MedicineType == 0)
                    {
                        ImageId.add(Images[1]);
                    }    } while(cur.moveToNext());
```

**also in myAdapter:**
I jst changed Integer Array to Integer Arraylist for Image

this solve my Problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also check in Adapter class like this

```
if(MedicineType==1)
{
    vHolder.imgMedicineType.setImageResource(imageA);
}
else if(MedicineType==0)
{
    vHolder.imgMedicineType.setImageResource(imageB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try to below code :-**

```
public PrescriptionAdapter(Context context,Integer[] ImageId,ArrayList<String>MedicineNames,ArrayList<String>MedicineType,
                           ArrayList<String>MedicineTimings,ArrayList<String>subMedicineTimings)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.ImageId = ImageId;
    this.MedicineNames = MedicineNames;
    this.MedicineType = MedicineType;
    this.MedicineTimings  = MedicineTimings;
    this.subMedicineTimings = subMedicineTimings;
}
public int getCount(){return MedicineNames.size();}
public Object getItem(int Position){return null;}
public long getItemId(int Position){return 0;}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_prescription_row, null,true);

        tvMedicineName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtMedicineName);
        tvMedicineTiming = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtMedicineTiming);
        tvSubMedicineTiming = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubMedicineTiming);
        imgMedicineType = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgPrescription);

        tvMedicineName.setText(MedicineNames.get(Position));
        tvMedicineTiming.setText(MedicineTimings.get(Position));
        tvSubMedicineTiming.setText(subMedicineTimings.get(Position));
        imgMedicineType.setImageResource(ImageId[Position]);
        return rowView;
  }
}
```

**Here is My Activity:**

```
 public int[] Images = {R.drawable.tablet,R.drawable.injection};
    public int[] ImageId = new int[]{} ;
```

**this is how i Assigning Images :**

```
ImageId = new int[Length];
                    if(MedicineType == 1){ImageId[i] = Images[0];}
                    else if(MedicineType == 0){ImageId[i]= Images[1];
```

Comment: have edited the part of main activity code in question itself